# Textarea not selectable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Is it possible in Google Chrome (I'm using 63.0.3239.132 version) to make a textarea unselectable (Only the inside text unselectable)?

In Edge, Explorer, and Firefox this code works, but not in Chrome.

Are there any other style properties to add?

```css
.mytextarea {
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="objLog" class="mytextarea" disabled="disabled" readonly style="background-color: #FFFFFF; width:400px; height:100px;">Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</textarea>
```

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome in the same version number as yours, 64 bits for OSX and your code works for me. I can't focus nor write in the textarea.

Comment: I think you can add `pointer-events: none;` and it should do the trick.

Comment: You can make an on mouse down event, get the id of the clicked element, and prevent default behaviour

Comment: @newbie in theory there is no need of JavaScript for something that works in CSS in almost every browser. Fabio_MO have you empty your browser cache?

Comment: @AnthonyB As you said, in ALMOST every browser, but he did not specified the solution he is looking for, and that's why I added this one, so he can choose :)

Comment: @newbie Indeed you're right to add this one, it's a working alternative. I think CSS should do the trick and the problem isn't here because it works on my Google Chrome using the same version, but it's a solution and he can choose :)

Comment: I tried all this solution but the behaviour still remain the same. Using pointer-event:none only the first line remain selectable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work too

```css
.mytextarea::selection {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="mytextarea" oncontextmenu="return false" readonly=”readonly” 
style="background-color: #FFFFFF; width:400px; height:100px;color:grey">
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        </textarea>
```

Comment: What did you change? Also don't delete and answer again if voted down.

Comment: This is the best solution for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @mplungjan i didn't put readonly="readonly" so i changed the solution ...!

Comment: In this, the user can select the test. this is because it does not appear to be simply selected by the user, but the text will be copy when the user press copy command.

Answer (score 3):

> Try the code below. The user will not be able to select any text with this CSS. And I've checked with many browsers, they are compatible with all browsers so you can use this CSS.

Because it is better to have a solution that can be used by other users, not just a questioner.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#objLog').bind("select", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text($(this).text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.mytextarea {
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  color:grey
}

.mytextarea::-moz-selection {
  color:grey;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.mytextarea::selection {
  color:grey;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="mytextarea" id="objLog" 
  onselect="return false;"
   readonly="readonly"
   unselectable="on"
   disabled="disabled"
>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</textarea>
```

Comment: Does not work....the behaviour is the same. Only ::selection in css "hide" the selection colour but the text still remain selectable

Comment: Not for me in Chrome 63 - I cannot select the text

Answer (score 2):

You can dot it with a wrapper div and no jQuery like this if you want:

```js
document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener('click', () => {
 
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle("disabled");

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

.disabled .mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 390px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.disabled .mytextarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1px;
  z-index: 0;
}
        
.mask {
   z-index:0;
}
  
.mytextarea {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper disabled">
  <div class="mask">

  </div>

  <textarea  id="objLog" class="mytextarea"  readonly style="background-color: #FFFFFF;height:92px;width: 394px; resize: none;">
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
    Test Test Test Test Test Test
  </textarea>
</div>

<button id="toggle" style="margin-top: 40px;">
toggle
</button>
```

Comment: It is almost what I'm searching for but with this solution it is not possible to scroll the text area when it is unselectable.

Comment: You're right. Just resize the mask width. Answer updated ! (but now the user can change the textarea size....)

Comment: To complete my previous comment, I just changed to the css resize property to none for the textarea.