# issue with disabling text selection of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are lots of non working answer on stackoverflow but I'm looking for a working one:

```js
const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
textarea.style.userSelect = 'none';
textarea.readOnly = true;
textarea.style.cursor = 'default';
textarea.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
```

```html
<textarea>
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

I want to disable text selection on this textarea in chrome (only) using pure javascript.

But for some reasons (perhaps a bug) this is not working!!

Comment: this code works. In which browser do you have a problem ?

Comment: Chrome..........

Comment: Yeah this is working on firefox... so it's a chrome's big??? any solution to fix this?

Comment: [Another version of the question with a jumble of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580163/textarea-not-selectable-in-chrome/48581020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very sure if this is what you are looking for. I presume you don't want the text to be selected on chrome and it should work fine on other browsers

```js
var isChrome = !!window.chrome;

if (isChrome) {
  const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  textarea.style.userSelect = 'none';
  textarea.readOnly = true;
  textarea.style.cursor = 'default';
  textarea.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
  textarea.setAttribute("onselectstart", "return false;");
  textarea.setAttribute("onmousedown", "return false;");
}
```

```html
<textarea>
Some content
</textarea>
```

Comment: Working like a charm on chrome...

Comment: @Sara Ree. Glad that worked!!